# jQuery Datepicker remove margins from cells

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I would like to remove the margins on the cells so there is no gap between them.

[image: example]

Tried this with no luck:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar td{margin-right: 0px !important;}
```

Comment: Are you intend to remove those borders too?

Comment: I want it exactly like the After pic. 1px border all the way around on every cell. The proposed answer moves the cells together, so it is 2px in some areas, which I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I needed the below in addition to padding:0

http://jsfiddle.net/edcxsw1/s08kkdht/

```
/* Full grid border */
.ui-datepicker-calendar td{
    border: 1px solid #D8D8D8 !important;
}

/* Remove the inner atag border */
.ui-state-default{

    border: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the padding on the cells to zero:

```
.ui-datepicker td {
    padding:0
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k9v5n389/)**

Comment: Anyway to remove the "double-border" on the connected cells? Notice how the top border is half the width